# Loop thru set of items and match every first 5 indexes,, then next 4 then next 6, and the all over gain, 5, 4 6

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code would look something similar, but I don't want to add more if statements if there is more items than 15. I need a pattern to pass as a parameter.

pattern = [5,4,6]?

```
function rearangeItems (items) {
    items.forEach((element, index) => {
       if (index < 5) {
            element.classList.add('col-fifth');
        } else if (index>=5 && index <=8) {
            element.classList.add('col-fourth');
        } else {
            element.classList.add('col-sixth');
    } 
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the modulo 15 of the index:

```
function rearangeItems(items) {
    items.forEach((element, index) => {
        const indexMod = index % 15;
        if (indexMod < 5) {
            element.classList.add('col-fifth');
        } else if (indexMod >= 5 && indexMod <= 8) {
            element.classList.add('col-fourth');
        } else {
            element.classList.add('col-sixth');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it generic for any pattern. Create a `pattern` array which has each chunk length and the class it is associated with

```
const pattern = [
  [5, 'col-fifth'],
  [4, 'col-fourth'],
  [6, 'col-sixth']
]
```

Then create a generator function which creates an array of classes filled chunk length times.

```
function* getClass(pattern) {
  const classes = pattern.flatMap(([n, cls]) => Array(n).fill(cls))

  while (true)
    yield* classes
}
```

The `classes` array looks:

```
['col-fifth', 'col-fifth', ...x5, 'col-fourth' x 4, 'col-sixth' x 6 times]
```

Use `while(true)` and [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) to return a class in that order as many times as it is requested.

Call the generator function inside `rearangeItems` like this:

```
function rearangeItems(items, pattern) {
  const gen = getClass(pattern);
  items.forEach((element) =>
    element.classList.add(gen.next().value)
  );
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
document.querySelector("ul")
        .innerHTML += Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => `<li>${i}</li>`).join("")

function rearangeItems(items, pattern) {
  const gen = getClass(pattern);
  items.forEach((element) =>
    element.classList.add(gen.next().value)
  );
}

function* getClass(pattern) {
  const classes = pattern.flatMap(([n, cls]) => Array(n).fill(cls))

  while (true)
    yield* classes
}

const pattern = [ [5, 'col-fifth'], [4, 'col-fourth'], [6, 'col-sixth'] ]

rearangeItems(document.querySelectorAll("li"), pattern)
```

```css
.col-fifth { color: red }
.col-fourth { color: green }
.col-sixth { color: yellow }
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Very useful this method.  Thank you for sharing!